# Проблема с количеством аргументов в библиотеке Autocad

Tags: python, .net, autocad, ironpython

Есть простенький пример, с помощью которого хочу подружиться с AutoCAD'ом

```
import clr
path = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\AutoCAD 2015\\"
clr.AddReferenceToFileAndPath(path + "accoremgd.dll")

import Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput as aaed

ed = aaed.Editor
print(ed.GetEntity.__doc__)
ed.WriteMessage("\nRegistered Python command:")
```

выдает следующее:

```
GetEntity(self: Editor, message: str) -> PromptEntityResult
GetEntity(self: Editor, options: PromptEntityOptions) ->    PromptEntityResult

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "autocad_01.py", line 21, in <module>
TypeError: WriteMessage() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Не пойму, какой второй аргумент ему нужен?

Comment: Судя по всему, нужно создать инстанс `ed = aaed.Editor(<нужные аргументы>)`, а не использовать сам класс

Answer (score 0):

Сразу оговорюсь, на Python для AutoCAD ничего не писал, но писал на C#. Если вы хотите получить доступ к консоли - вам нужен открытый документ. Попробуйте закрыть все окна в AutoCAD - видите, никакой консоли нет. Вам нужно добраться до Editor через активный документ. На C# это выглядит так:

```
Editor ed = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor
```

На Python попробуйте такой код:

```
from Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices import *
from  Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices import *
from Autodesk.AutoCAD.EditorInput import *
from  Autodesk.AutoCAD.Runtime import * 
doc = Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument
ed = doc.Editor
```

Comment: >>> ed = Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.DocumentManager.MdiActiveDocument.Editor
      ' Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
        AttributeError: 'Autodesk.AutoCAD.ApplicationServices' object has  no attribute 'Application'

Comment: @TuborgSkorp нагуглиг вам код